# difference between specify by reference and transformation name in transformation job entry

Tags: pentaho, kettle, spoon

What is the difference between the 'specify by reference' and transformations file name in the transformation step while creating jobs. ?!

I am specifying the path to a ktr file in the transformation filename textbox . the path is relative to the kettle.bat file.

What is the difference between what I have entered and the specify by reference textbox. I am specifying by reference in the first text box itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically Three things while we define the transformation name in the Job:

**1. Transformation Filename:**

Using this you can locate a .ktr file either in the local directory. This will read the xml file.

**2. Specify by Name and Directory:**

This is enabled when you are connected to any repository. Using this, you can locate any **.ktr** file by its **Name** available in the repository.

**3. Specify by reference:**

This is also enabled when you are connected to a PDI Enterprise Repository. The only difference is, here you read a file by its unique identifier or reference. Even if you change the name of the file, this step will try to locate the file by its reference id. These reference id's are stored in the repo. directory.

You can check more on this in [wiki here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Transformation+(job+entry)).

Hope it helps :)